# can not get singularity to compile, failed to get package version

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, singularity-container

Ubuntu 20.04, downloaded singularity 3.7.3.tar.gz, sha256 matches, unzipped it and followed instructions but keep getting
`Failed to get package version. Abort.`

Any quick suggestions what I'm missing.  I installed GO using a snap, and when I check the version I get

`$ go version go version go1.16.3 linux/amd64` 
What am I missing.  Thx, J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a bug / problem!

In the file
`/singularity/mconfig`

is some code to check the version?

```
# if test -z "${package_version}" ; then
#   echo "Failed to get package version. Abort."
#   exit 1
# fi
```

I can't tell why this doesn't work because the file it is looking for is present.
If I comment out this code, the config, compile and install work seamlessly and do produce the correct version information!  The syslabs.io people make it incredibly difficult to contact them to suggest a bug.

V2, got it to work, this is new to me but the quirk was I was downloading the .tar.gz into a directory that was already within a git repo.  This affects where mconfig looks for the "VERSION" file and causes an error.  Created a new directory outside any git repo's, dowloaded, untarred and mconfig,make, and make install all worked fine.  Strange thae where it looks for VERSION file is changed?